# How to place more than one ChartLabel in a BarChart

Tags: plotting, graphics, charts

I have the following data:

```
data = {{493, 416}, {1330, 1586, 1579, 1424, 1667, 1023, 665}, {1963, 
    428, 1797, 1832, 1697, 549, 526}, {1742, 2040, 1767, 1876, 1680, 
    668, 531}, {1751, 1565, 1577, 1693, 1691, 584, 523}, {1356}};

days = {{Saturday, Sunday}, {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, 
    Friday, Saturday, Sunday}, {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, 
    Friday, Saturday, Sunday}, {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, 
    Friday, Saturday, Sunday}, {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, 
    Friday, Saturday, Sunday}, {Monday}};

daysnum = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
    16}, {17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}, {24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
    30}, {31}};
```

I want to plot a BarChart and to use more than one ChartLabel.  I have created a handmade picture so that you can know what I mean.

[image]

How can I create a ChartLabel at the x-axis and at the center and the top of the BarChart?
Is it possible to color a ChartLabel according to the Bars colors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the following is that you are loosing the *depth* of the initial list `data` since I only found a way to do it thanks to `Flatten`.

```
data = {{493, 416}, {1330, 1586, 1579, 1424, 1667, 1023, 665}, {1963, 
    428, 1797, 1832, 1697, 549, 526}, {1742, 2040, 1767, 1876, 1680, 
    668, 531}, {1751, 1565, 1577, 1693, 1691, 584, 523}, {1356}};

(* version 8 *)
col = Cases[BarChart@data, RGBColor[__], Infinity][[2 ;;]];
(* version 9 *)
(* col = Cases[BarChart@data, RGBColor[__], Infinity]; *)

days = {{Saturday, Sunday}, {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, 
    Friday, Saturday, Sunday}, {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, 
    Friday, Saturday, Sunday}, {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, 
    Friday, Saturday, Sunday}, {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, 
    Friday, Saturday, Sunday}, {Monday}};
days = ToString /@ days[[#]] & /@ Range@Length@days;
days = Style[#, #2] & @@@ Thread[{Flatten@days, col}];

daysnum = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
    16}, {17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}, {24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
    30}, {31}};
daysnum = ToString /@ daysnum[[#]] & /@ Range@Length@daysnum;

BarChart[Labeled[#, #2, Above] & @@@ 
    Thread[{Flatten[data, 1], Flatten[daysnum, 1]}],
  ChartLabels -> {Placed[Flatten@days, Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/2] &]}, 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, Center, Rotate[#, Pi/2] &] &),
  ImageSize -> 500, ChartStyle -> col, BarSpacing -> .2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

About the version issue with `col`:

In *version 8*

```
Cases[BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}}], RGBColor[__], Infinity] // Length
```

> 4

while it apparently returns `3` in *version 9*.

Comment: Perfect. I want to just mention one thing, I think you need to change col = Cases[BarChart@data, RGBColor[__], Infinity][[2 ;;]] to col = Cases[BarChart@data, RGBColor[__], Infinity][[1 ;;]], otherwise the Thread will not work of unequal lengths list.

Comment: The length of `Cases[BarChart@data, RGBColor[], Infinity]` is 32, `Length@Flatten@data` is 31. You need the `2;;` or it's not the same length. See [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy3UX.png). Plus, the right first colour is the second one

Comment: if I copy paste the code you wrote, it will give error unless I remove the [[2;;]] from end of col.

Comment: very string, when I find col = Cases[BarChart@data, RGBColor[__], Infinity]; Length@col it returns 31.

Comment: @Algohi, what version are you using?

Comment: 9.0.1.0, I am getting length of Cases[BarChart@data, RGBColor[__], Infinity]//Length =31.

Comment: It may be a version issue then.. :)

Comment: @Algohi How many do you get for `Cases[BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}}], RGBColor[__], Infinity] // Length`?

Comment: @ Öskå I got 3. what about you?

Comment: @Algohi I do have 4.

Comment: Any explanation of this? do you know what is the reason?

Comment: @Algohi No clue, probably some internal changes.. :) I guess updating from v8 to v9 means changing a few functions :)

Comment: I may tell you that for Cases[BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}}], RGBColor[__], Infinity] // Length, I get 3, and for Cases[BarChart[{1, 2, 3}], RGBColor[__], Infinity] // Length, I get 4.

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{493, 416}, {1330, 1586, 1579, 1424, 1667, 1023, 665},
   {1963, 428, 1797, 1832, 1697, 549, 526},
   {1742, 2040, 1767, 1876, 1680, 668, 531},
   {1751, 1565, 1577, 1693, 1691, 584, 523}, {1356}};

 days = {{Saturday, Sunday},
   {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday},
   {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday},
   {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday},
   {Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, 
    Sunday}, {Monday}};

 daysnum = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16},
   {17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23}, {24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30}, {31}};
```

Restructuring data into a more easily used form:

```
 data2 = Partition[Thread[Flatten /@ {data, days, daysnum}], 7, 7, 1, {}];
```

I believe that this is what you asked for

EDIT : Corrected colors

```
Module[{len = Length[data2], colors}, 
 colors = Table[ColorData["Rainbow"][(n - 1)/6], {n, 7}];
 BarChart[Map[
   Labeled[#[[1]], {Rotate[#[[1]], Pi/2], 
      Style[#[[3]], colors[[Mod[#[[3]] - 1, 7] + 1]]]}, {Center, Above}] &, 
   data2, {2}], ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", ChartLabels -> (n = 1;
    Rotate[Style[#, colors[[n++]]], Pi/2] & /@ data2[[1, All, 2]])]]
```

[image]

However, you  might want to consider using `ChartLegends` rather than `ChartLabels`

```
 Module[{len = Length[data2], colors}, 
 colors = Table[ColorData["Rainbow"][(n - 1)/6], {n, 7}];
 BarChart[
  Map[Labeled[#[[1]], {Rotate[#[[1]], Pi/2], 
      Style[#[[3]], colors[[Mod[#[[3]] - 1, 7] + 1]]]}, {Center, 
      Above}] &, data2, {2}], ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", 
  ChartLegends -> (n = 1;
    Style[#, colors[[n++]]] & /@ data2[[1, All, 2]])]]
```

[image]

Comment: Corrected colors for labels

Answer (score 3):

```
d = ToString /@ Flatten@days;
n = # <> "  " & /@ ToString /@ Range@Length@d;
nd = StringJoin[n[[#]], d[[#]]] & /@ Range@Length@d;

BarChart[Flatten@data,
 ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain",
 ImageSize -> 600,
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Rotate[#, Pi/4], Above] &),
 ChartElementFunction -> "SegmentScaleRectangle",
 ChartLabels -> Map[Rotate[#, Pi/2] &, nd]]
```

[image]

```
d = StringTake[#, 3] & /@ ToString /@ Flatten@days;
d = StringJoin[d[[#]], Table["  ", {Length@d}][[#]]] & /@ Range@Length@d;
n = # <> "  " & /@ ToString /@ Range@Length@d;
nd = StringJoin[n[[#]], d[[#]]] & /@ Range@Length@d;

BarChart[Reverse@Flatten@data,
 BarOrigin -> Left,
 ColorFunction -> "DarkTerrain",
 ImageSize -> 600,
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#, Right] &),
 ChartElementFunction -> "SegmentScaleRectangle",
 ChartLabels -> Reverse@nd]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
rule = Thread[days[[2]] -> Range[7]];
cdF = ColorData[63];
(* for Gradient schemes use, e.g., cdF = ColorData[{"Rainbow", {1, 7}}] *)

BarChart[Apply[
               Labeled[Style[#1, cdF[Mod[(#3 /. rule), 7, 1]]],
                       {Rotate[Style[#1, 12], 90 Degree],
                       Style[#2, 14, cdF[Mod[(#3 /. rule), 7, 1]]], 
                       Rotate[Style[#3, 14, cdF[Mod[(#3 /. rule), 7, 1]]], 90 Degree]},
                     {Center, Above, Below}] &,
              Thread /@ Thread[{data, daysnum, days}], {2}],
        ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the answer that I am looking for. great thanks.