# BarChart with two ChartLabels

Tags: plotting, charts

I am creating a BarChart, where i wish to have the actual value on the top of each bar and the label of the bar on the bottom. Basically i have created the BarChart with the label in the bottom, but i cannot figure out how to add the value on the top of each bar.

```
values = {150445, 161419, 173986, 202405, 214516, 227004, 
   240700, 256377, 271309, 286944, 307016, 320545};
labels = {2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008,
    2009, 2010, 2011, 2012};
Show[
 BarChart[values, ChartLabels -> labels, 
  ChartStyle -> "Pastel", AxesLabel -> {"Year", "Diagnosis"}],
 Background -> Transparent,
 BaseStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
 ImageSize -> 600
 ]
```

Is there a way to view the `values`on top of each bar?

Comment: From [related Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/50991/125): `BarChart[Labeled[#, #, Above] & /@ values, ChartLabels -> labels,  ChartStyle -> "Pastel", AxesLabel -> {"Year", "Diagnosis"}]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 BarChart[Labeled[#, {#, #2}, {Above, Below}] & @@@ Thread[{values, Most@labels}],
   ChartStyle -> "Pastel", 
   AxesLabel -> {"Year", "Diagnosis"}, Background -> Transparent, 
   BaseStyle -> {12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hackish, but it is convenient in this case:

```
BarChart[
 AssociationThread[labels, values],
 ChartLabels -> Automatic,
 LabelingFunction -> Above
]
```